# Equivalent definitions of a measurable set in a manifold

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, differential-geometry

There seem to be at least two ways of defining measurability in a smooth $n$-manifold $M$, and I want to know if these definitions are equivalent.

(1) For the first one, we say $A\subseteq M$ is measurable if for each coordinate chart $(U,\varphi)$, $\varphi(A\cap U)$ is a Lebesgue measurable set in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

The second one is a little complicated and goes as follows.

(2) $A\subseteq M$ is said to be measurable if it can be written as a countable union of sets $A_i$ with each $A_i$ contained in some coordinate chart $(U_i,\varphi_i)$ and thus mapped onto a Lebesgue measurable set $\varphi_i(A_i)$.

Now I'd like to determine whether or not (1)$\Leftrightarrow$(2). To prove the first definition implies the second one, I want to exploit the notion of compactness, because every open cover of a compact set contains a finite subcover. That might be helpful if we want to break $A$ into countably many pieces. However, I don't have too much information about $A$. Maybe it is not compact at all. Then what should I do? Thank you.

Comment: If you replace $M$ by $\mathbb{R}^n$ in definition (2) you get a new definition for measurability there. I think it is equivalent to the usual one because a countable union of measurable sets is measurable. If one can prove this rigorously this proof should 'lift' to manifolds.

Comment: Do you have any particular reason for using this notion of measurability? You could just work with Borel sets in $M$. And if you have e.g. a Riemannian metric on $M$, you can always take the completion with respect to the volume measure.

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz Thank you. I just want to unify these two concepts. They make me filled with anxiety.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Item (2) should be written more carefully. The phrase "and thus" seems inappropriate: just because $A_i$ is contained in the coordinate chart $(U_i,\phi_i)$ it does follows that $\phi_i(A_i)$ is a measurable subset. In fact measurability of $\phi_i(A_i)$ should be imposed as a condition. So (2) should be instead say

> (2) A subset $A \subset M$ is measurable if $A$ can be written as a countable union of sets $A_i$, and for each $i$ there is a coordinate chart $(U_i,\phi_i)$, such that $A_i \subset U_i$ and such that $\phi_i(A_i) \subset \mathbb R^n$ is Lebesgue measurable.

To prove equivalence of (1) and (2), your idea of breaking $A$ into countably many pieces is very important, but I don't think compactness is particularly relevant. On the other hand, you can apply second countability of $M$ to choose a countable collection of coordinate charts $(U_i,\phi_i)$ so that the sets $U_i$ form a countable basis of $M$. You can then quickly prove (1)$\implies$(2) by taking $A_i = A \cap U_i$.

To prove the converse direction (2)$\implies$(1), consider any coordinate chart $(U,\phi)$ as in (1). From (2) we are given a countable collection of coordinate charts $(U_i,\phi_i)$ and a subset $A_i \subset A \cap U_i$ so that $A = \cup_i A_i$ and so that $\phi_i(A_i)$ is measurable in $\mathbb R^n$. We are assuming that $M$ has a countable basis, and therefore we can choose a countable collection of coordinate charts $(V_j,\psi_j)$ such that $U = \cup_j (U \cap V_j)$, and it follows that $A \cap U =  \cup_{i,j} (A_i \cap V_j)$. For each of the countably many ordered pairs of indices $(i,j)$, notice that $U_i \cap V_j$ is open in $U_i$, so $\phi_i(U_i \cap V_j)$ is open in $\mathbb R^n$, so the set
$$\phi_i(A_i \cap V_j) = \phi_i(A_i \cap U_i \cap V_j) = \phi_i(A_i) \cap \phi_i(U_i \cap V_j)
$$
is measurable in $\mathbb R^n$. Applying smoothness of the overlap map
$$\phi \circ \phi_i^{-1} : \phi_i(U \cap U_i) \to \phi(U \cap U_i)
$$
it follows that $\phi(A_i \cap V_j)$ is measurable in $\mathbb R^n$. Taking the union over the countable set of index pairs $(i,j)$ it follows that $\phi(A \cap U)$ is measurable in $\mathbb R^n$, as required to prove (1).

Comment: Sorry, that's my bad. The statement of (2) should have been put like yours. Yeah, that's a definition. I just wanted to emphasize "via a specific chart".

Comment: Could you tell me why $\phi_{i(n)}(A \cap U_{i(n)})$ is measurable in the proof of the converse direction, please? Where are those $A_i$'s?

Comment: I simplified the notation and fixed a bad typo (a union sign which had been incorrectly written as an intersection sign).

Comment: Thank you, but I think there is a logical issue. In the proof of (2)$\implies$(1), we should act on the premise that $A=\cup_i A_i$, where each $A_i$ is contained in a chart $(U_i,\phi_i)$ with $\phi_i(A_i)$ measurable in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I'm afraid we can't coin a whole new $A_i$ like you did in $A_i=A \cap U_i$. We must take care of those old $A_i$'s.

Comment: I was alluding to that when saying "you may then take $A_i = A \cap U_i$". Whatever your original collection of $A_i$'s is, or better, let's call them $A_j$'s, you then replace them by their intersections with the $U_i$'s. I can say more about that later, if you like... but cannot at the moment.

Comment: That would be wonderful if it is convenient for you.

Comment: I made that last step explicit.

Comment: Thank you, but seriously, are you sure about $$\phi_i(A_i \cap U_i \cap V_j) = \phi_i(A_i) \cap \phi_i(U_i \cap V_j)?$$ There exists a counter-example to show that $$f(C\cap D)\neq f(C)\cap f(D).$$ All we can say about these two sets is that $$f(C\cap D)\subseteq f(C)\cap f(D),$$ which is why I couldn't understand the early version of your proof.

Comment: $\phi_i$ is a homeomorphism, and therefore a bijection, from the set $U_i$ to the subset $\phi_i(U_i) \subset \mathbb R^n$. For any bijection $f : X \to Y$ and for any subsets $C,D \subset X$, it is true that $f(C \cap D) = f(C) \cap f(D)$.

Comment: Gosh, I wish I could have met you earlier! Your valuable advice will refine many of my proofs in my early years. By the way, the condition for $f(C \cap D) = f(C) \cap f(D)$ to be true can relax from bijectivity to injectivity.